# Issues with HttpURLConnection with POST on android 2.2

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am having some issue doing some POST request on android 2.2, everything works fine in newer version 4.0+. The request i am doing is an https request as well. I always get a 400 Bad request. Here's the code I am using:

```
public String postRequest(String myurl, String requestBody) throws IOException {
     try {
              //Create connection
              URL url = new URL(myurl);
              connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
              connection.setRequestMethod("POST");  

              for (Map.Entry<String, String> headerMap : httpHeaders.entrySet()) {
                  connection.setRequestProperty(headerMap.getKey(), headerMap.getValue());
                    Log.d("HttpRequest", " headers Key = " + headerMap.getKey() + ", Value = " + headerMap.getValue());
              }

              connection.setUseCaches (false);
              connection.setDoOutput(true);


              if(requestBody != null && requestBody.length() > 0) {
                  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
                           Integer.toString(requestBody.getBytes().length));

                  connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(requestBody.getBytes().length);
    //            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    //            Log.v("RESPONSE MESSAGE", connection.getResponseMessage());
                  //Send request
                  OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
                  out.write(requestBody.getBytes());
                  out.flush();
                  out.close();
                  Log.v("RESPONSE MESSAGE", myurl + " "+ connection.getResponseMessage());
              }

              int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
              Log.w("HttpRequest rponse code:", myurl+" - "+responseCode);
              if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED) {
                  //    Get Response    
                  InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                  String line;
                  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
                  while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                    response.append('\r');
                  }
                  rd.close();

                  return response.toString();
              } else {
    //            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
                  InputStream error = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getErrorStream();
                  Log.e("HTTP error", "Error, request failed code: "+ responseCode + " "+connection.getResponseMessage() +" \n " + error);
                  return null;
              }

            } catch (Exception e) {

              e.printStackTrace();
              return null;

            } finally {

              if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect(); 
              }
            }   
}
```

Also, I am posting a xml body.

```
<SetAchievementsCompletedByConsoleSpecificKeyRESTXML xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><platformActionKeys xmlns:ns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'><ns:string>1</ns:string></platformActionKeys></SetAchievementsCompletedByConsoleSpecificKeyRESTXML>
```

Comment: Since a POST request is normally `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, where are you specifying the MIME type of this content? What is your server log telling you?

Comment: Is it necessary to have application/x-ww-form-urlencoded if I am just posting an xml body and not form values? I am getting a 400 response code Bad request

Comment: "Is it necessary to have application/x-ww-form-urlencoded if I am just posting an xml body and not form values?" -- `application/x-ww-form-urlencoded` is wrong in this case, but sometimes the server is expecting a proper MIME type for whatever the data is (`text/xml`?). You would have to ask whoever wrote your server what is expected, probably at the same time when you ask him or her how to look at server logs to get more information than a 400 response code.

Comment: I am specifying the Content-type as text/xml. What is weird that, this works perfectly with the latest 4.0+ android build. I am only having this issue on < 4.0 versions.

Comment: That's why I am hoping that there is some way that you can get more diagnostic information from your server than just a 400 return code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. For some weird reason. When added my header with my hearderMap, it was adding extra whitespaces. This corrected my header:

```
connection.setRequestProperty(headerMap.getKey().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""), headerMap.getValue().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
```